# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchrow'

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, asyncpg

I was using MySQL database before, and now I've migrated to **PostgreSQL**.
Looks like it is very hard to refactor my code for Postgres.
I am experiencing some troubles with **`find_and_lock_token()` method**.

```
async def init_db_connection():
        global conn
        conn = await asyncpg.connect(
            user=await get_username(),
            password=await get_pass(),
            host=await get_host(),
            port=await get_port(),
            database=await get_username()
        )

# Working with table named "Tokens", Column names: "Token", "Status", "Name", "ActivityToken"
# Content of the columns | "Token": random token; "Status": 'Busy'/'Free'; "Name": random name; "ActivityToken": random token

async def find_and_lock_token(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            token = await conn.fetchrow(
                'SELECT "Token" FROM "Tokens" WHERE "Status" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED',
                'Free'
            )

            if token is not None:
                token = token['Token']
                await conn.execute(
                    'UPDATE "Tokens" SET "Status" = $1 WHERE "Token" = $2',
                    'Busy', token
                )
                return token
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error finding and locking token: {e}")

await init_db_connection()
token = await find_and_lock_token(conn)
```

I have tried bunch of different variations using **`fetchrow()`, `fetchval()` etc.**
*Everything throws me this 'NoneType'error.*

**I need this `find_and_lock_token` method to work as follows:**

1. Find the random "Token" that has 'Free' "Status",
2. Take this token, and imediately set it's "Status" to 'Busy'.
3. If there is no 'Free' tokens in our "Tokens" table, then wait until 'Free' token will appear, and try to take it then.

All these columns have 'TEXT' type.

I got few **'onLaunch'** checks saying that **I am connected to the database** (very quickly, approx 1-2 seconds.) meaning this is not the trouble.

I checked, by adding delay after connection that **`con`** could not be `NoneType` (as  **nicomp** said in comments). Or it is but by different cause, I don't understand why.

Comment: None is the type you get when something goes wrong and you need a placeholder. Your issue is before you are trying to use the thing that is of the None type. Look in the code where that thing is initialized, because it's not initialized to what you think of should be. It looks like your connection attempt is failing or is just taking too long.

Comment: Have you tried returning `conn` from the `iinit_db_connection` function instead of setting it as a global?

Comment: @snakecharmerb oh shoot! Yeah! You are right.. Man!!!! I just have fixed it!!! I was using "await get_username()", so never use asynchronous methods when you are building your credentials for connection! Logging the `con` was very important. 
Everything works fine now!

Thanks guys! Shout out to @nicomp and @snakecharmerb ! <3 ;)

Comment: I'm not going to answer, because I can't explain _why_ my guess was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> None is the type you get when something goes wrong and you need a placeholder. Your issue is before you are trying to use the thing that is of the None type. Look in the code where that thing is initialized, because it's not initialized to what you think of should be. It looks like your connection attempt is failing or is just taking too long. – @nicomp

> Have you tried returning conn from the init_db_connection function instead of setting it as a global? – @snakecharmerb

The answer was to make some much advanced logging.
I got a**`'NoneType'`** error, meaning that the **`conn` OBJECT** of `asyncpg.connect()` had a value of **`None`**. And so when **`fetchrow()`** was trying to access **`conn | asyncpg.connect()` object** it could not do that because my credentials were built by asynchronous methods. Never overuse async.

Conclusion.
**Never do little logging. If you have done logging, you have done little logging. Always do as much logging as possible.**
;) <3